# Importing css file in jsx using relative path

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I feel a bit silly asking this, but I'm having trouble with resolving a relative path in my React app.

Where I want to import the css:

```
src/components/pages/mypage.js
```

Where my css file is located:

```
src/custom_styles/sidebar.css
```

How I'm trying to import `sidebar.css` in `mypage.js`:

```
import '.../custom_styles/sidebar.css'
```

This is resulting in `Module not found: Can't resolve '.../custom_styles/sidebar.css'` in the console when compiling. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Only use two periods.`import '../custom_styles/sidebar.css'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import '../../custom_styles/sidebar.css';` in your `mypage.js` file.

`../` means that you're going one level up from your current file. In your case you have to move two ups.

Answer (score 1):

```
import '../../../custom_styles/sidebar.css'
```

Each time you want o get to the parent folder add `../` so if you want to get to 3 folders above use `../../../` , not `.../`